# Views slideshow pager as menu tabs

Tags: 7, views

I wondering if this is possible.
I can not find any information on this topic, but I am trying to make my pager that is in a Views slideshow into the menu tabs of my navigation, so that if I scroll over the "home" menu button, the image would change, or if I scroll over "about us," the image would change to the "about us" image. Can anyone give me some suggestions on what I can do to achieve this?

Comment: So you want the pager to have two functions? Load a new page and change a slideshow? If you have a better example with images it may help find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using views and and a contextual filter, the module has since then been updated to enable the hover function on each field.

Answer (score 0):

[Views Slideshow Menu](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_menu). Only works with 2.x at the moment.

Comment: that completely broke views 3...

Answer (score 0):

Views slideshow use cycle plugin (a jquery plugin) to change the slides and other activities.

This code navigates your slideshow to next slide when you scroll over a menu item:

```
$('YOUR MENU ITEM').hover(function () {
  $('YOUR VIEWS SLIDESHOW BLOCK ID').cycle('next');
});
```

To see list of all the functions and methods of jquery cycle plugin visit: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html